# Database.query not returning records properly as needed

Tags: apex, soql, query

I am using database.query to extract records. I am passing a query from the front end.The query can be anything.
But I am not getting the records properly in return.

For example, if I am passing the below query:

```
String query = 'SELECT fax FROM Account LIMIT 5';
Sobject[] objData = Database.query(query);
system.debug('myData::'+objData);
```

On debug I am getting this:

```
(
 Account:{Fax=905-882-5801, Id=0013000000BcUfoAAF}, 
 Account:{Fax=415-683-2349, Id=0013000000BcUfpAAF}, 
 Account:{Id=0013000000BcUfqAAF}, 
 Account:{Fax=+61-292-417954, Id=0013000000BcUfrAAF}, 
 Account:{Fax=408-588-1296, Id=0013000000BcUfsAAF}
 )
```

As you can see, the third record does not have Fax column inside. I need it to be like this:  `Account:{Fax=null, Id=0013000000BcUfqAAF}`

How to acheive that? Can it be done using something else other than Database.query. I want max 50,000 records.

Answer (score 6):

The field is there, but it's not being printed out by default. If you try

```
system.debug('myData::'+JSON.serialize(objData));
```

you will get the null value as well. So for your intents, all the data is in place.

Comment: nice answer !!!Wish i had one more vote to vote this!

Answer (score 4):

```
String query = 'SELECT fax FROM Account LIMIT 5';
Sobject[] objData = Database.query(query);
system.debug('myData::'+objData[2].fax);//Changed the line
```

Please note even in the log you will not get Fax=null if field has no value but when you access this into a variable it will be null .

Please see the change i have done to the code in debug line .

Comment: I need the column names also, to pass in my jqery table. How can I get all the columns from the results?

Comment: can you post the jquery code of you dont mind ?